# Hanging when working with basic types in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

In a program, I want to display the number "`0.12345`" as "`.12345`" (removing the first zero) in a `lineEdit`. For this I wrote the simple code below:

```
QString s;
QTextStream ss(&s);

double temp = 0.12345;
int n = 0;

if(temp > 0)
{
    ss << ".";
    while (true)
    {
        temp *= 10;
        n = temp;
        if (temp == n)
            break;
    }
    ss << n;
}
lineEdit->setText(s);
```

When I run it, the program and Qt Creator hang and I need to rerun it to normally go out of it.

What is the problem that the program acts that way, please?

Comment: I am confused is it the compiler itself, that _hangs_ (define _hang_), or your compiled code? Also, not related to your issue, but `n = temp; if(temp == n) break;` in a while loop will break out of your loop on the first iteration.

Comment: I meant that the compiler suspends. since `n` is *int* and `temp` a *double* so in first iteration the loop does not finished.

Comment: oh, didn't notice the types of variables. Sorry. But you do realize, that, floating point numbers are only approximations, and may not be stored exactly as you write them? In addition: why such difficult parsing algorithm? What's wrong with `std::stringstream ss; ss << temp; std::string s = ss.str (); s.erase (s.begin());`? [Example](http://ideone.com/97eOGJ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem

Your program never exits the `while` loop because you are comparing the floating point numbers using the `==` operator. This leads to miscalculation (you can read more about it [here](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2006/08/12/floating_point_approximation/)).

#### Solution

The proper way to check the `double` variables equality in Qt is to use the [`qFuzzyCompare`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qFuzzyCompare) function:

```
if (qFuzzyCompare(temp, n)) {
    break;
}
```

#### Simplification

If understand your task correctly, your code is too complicated for it. This should do the whole job:

```
double num = 0.12345;
if (num > 0 && num < 1) {
    QString str = QString::number(num).remove(0, 1);
    lineEdit->setText(str);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. While your opinion (on using the operator *==* for *double* and *int*) is not right, but your *simplification*, especially **.remove** solved the issue. Thanks again.

Comment: @franky Glad to know that everything works fine now. Just of curiosity, why do you think that the advice to **not** compare floating point numbers using the `==` operator is wrong? This classic issue was widely discussed and described (e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682889/is-floating-point-ever-ok/4951103), [here](http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/), [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)).