# QE solve and a check if the roots satisfy the equation : using C language

Tags: c, format, printf

I am writing a code in C. Checking the roots if they satisfy the quadratic equation.
In `printf`, while `%lf` outputs `0`, `%e` returns a very small value (between 10<sup>-15</sup> and 10<sup>-19</sup>).
I tried to declare the variable as `float` or `double`, nothing is working when I am printing using `%e`. What is wrong?

Also any suggestions to improve the logic would be appreciated. I am a beginner in C. thanks.

----------------------code-------------------------------

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

struct param {
    double a[11];
} x, y, z;

double slvequad(double a1, double b1, double c1) {
    double quad_sol1, quad_sol2;
    double dcrm = b1 * b1 - 4.0 * a1 * c1;
    printf("\n ( %+0.2e, %+0.2e, %+0.2e)", a1, b1, c1);

    if (a1 != 0 && dcrm >= 0) {
        quad_sol1 = (-b1 + sqrt(dcrm)) / (2.0 * a1);
        quad_sol2 = (-b1 - sqrt(dcrm)) / (2.0 * a1);
        printf("( %+0.2e , %+0.2e ) ", quad_sol1, quad_sol2);
        quadcheck(a1, b1, c1, quad_sol1, quad_sol2);
    } else
    if (a1 == 0 && b1 != 0) {
        quad_sol1 = quad_sol2 = -c1 / b1;
        printf("( %+0.2e  ) ", quad_sol1);
        quadcheck(a1, b1, c1, quad_sol1, quad_sol2);
    } else {
        printf(" No solution  ");
    }
}

void quadcheck(double x1, double y1, double z1, double sol1, double sol2) {

    double v1 = (x1 * (sol1) * (sol1) + y1 * sol1 + z1);
    double v2 = (x1 * (sol2) * (sol2) + y1 * sol2 + z1);

    printf("( %+0.2e , %+0.2e ) \n ", v1, v2);
}

int main() {
    struct param x = { 1e-10, 0,  1, 0, 0, 1e-35, 1,  3, 4,   1,  1.0  };
    struct param y = { 2.0,   1,  0, 1, 0, 0,     4,  5, -20, 6,  -1e-1 };
    struct param z = { 1e-10, 5, -4, 0, 0, -1e35, 1, -7, 25,  34, 0.0025 };
    int i;

    int len = *(&x.a + 1) - x.a;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        slvequad(x.a[i], y.a[i], z.a[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

output: In format:  (a1,b1,c1)(quad_sol1, quad_sol2)(v1,v1)
[image]

Technically, `v1` and `v2` should print `0`, but it prints very small value in a few cases (using `%e`) as shown in the image.

Comment: Post your code here as _text_. Best as a [mcve].

Comment: Code is _working_.  %lf returns an answer  _rounded_ to the nearest 0.000001.  %e provides more detail.  What might be wrong is the unposted code that calculated the answer.

Comment: Your code snippet linked does not show the actual value of `s1` and `s2` anywhere. Is the problem that "very small" is supposed to be exactly 0?

Comment: Often, the exact roots cannot be represented exactly and you need to check if they are close enough to 0, or check for a sign change in the function value close to the candidate root.

Comment: @WeatherVane yes should be zero. the quadcheck was to check the roots putting back in QE, hence it should be zero.

Comment: Please see [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)
and [Why Are Floating Point Numbers Inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate)
and [Is floating-point == ever OK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682889/is-floating-point-ever-ok)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The roots for *x<sup>2</sup> + 4x + 1* are irrational numbers *-2 +/-sqrt(3)*. They cannot be represented exactly in types `float` or `double`, only approximations are stored, precise to about 17 significant digits for type `double`. Computing the polynomial with these approximations produce very small, yet non zero numbers.

You may want to read these questions:

- [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)
- [Why are floating point numbers inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate)
- [Is floating-point == ever OK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682889/is-floating-point-ever-ok)